# Showing the irreducibility of a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}$[x].

Tags: polynomials

I am currently practicing for my first Abstract Algebra II exam (with a focus in Galois theory) and I came across the following practice problem in my textbook:

[image]

How do we know that $bd=1$, $ad+bc=8$, $ac+b+d=-2$ and $a+c=0$? I feel like I’m overlooking something elementary but I cannot seem to resolve it.

Comment: If you expand out the product of the two polynomials in the factorization, the coefficients have to agree with the coefficients of $x^{4}-2x^{2}+8x+1$. Each equality comes from one coefficient.

Comment: Did you miss "Equating coefficients of powers of $x$..."?  Recall that - by definition - (formal) polynomials are equal $\iff$ they have equal coefficient sequences. It's just the **method of undetermined coefficients** applied to a product of polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From equating coefficients of powers of $x$ in the equation

$(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)=x^4+0x^3-2x^2+8x+1$

$=x^4+(a+c)x^3+(ac+b+d)x^2+(ad+bc)x+bd$

we know that $a+c=0, ac+b+d=-2, ad+bc=8,$ and $bd=1.$

Answer (score 0):

If two real polynomials are equal as functions then their corresponding co-efficients are equal.

BTW. If $bd=1$ with $b,d \in \Bbb Z$ then $b=d=1$ or $b=d=-1,$ so $b=d.$ But then, since $c=-a,$  we have$$8=ad+bc=ad+b(-a)=a(d-b)=a\cdot 0=0.$$